# Screen sharing application in java

Tags: java, synchronization, screen-capture, data-transfer

I am working on screen sharing in java. I am capturing screenshots continuously and now I want to send/sync this data from my machine to another. Can I do this without having a need for separate machine acting as a server (like peer to peer networking) or with only a little server intervention?

Comment: i made a similar application in c#, trick i used was one machine was continuously listening to a specific port, the other just sent image bytes to that port!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html

Comment: you are not meaning p2p network but direct socket connection between the two computers ?

Comment: @jurka, yes i mean two machines on network should be able to communicate each other without server or with little server intervention

Comment: Then yes the multiple ports is the key for that. Use one port for sending command and the other for the data transportation.

Comment: @MuhammadYasir, how efficient your approach was in terms of no of frames per seconds received at destination?

Comment: after compressing image and some optimizations, I received ~20+ fps over 100mbps connection. I use timer dependent technique to limit frames.

Comment: @MuhammadYasir have you used any other compression other than JPEG?

Comment: I was using PNG, and lowering the quality using ImageEncoders

Comment: @helpermethod your suggested approach looks perfect for transfer ,but is there any limitations on this approach such as 1.no of packets that can be sent per second 2.size of packet